# Bash scripting - 'type' return value different in init script

Tags: linux, bash

Can someone please explain this to me:

```
$ type blah
bash: type: blah: not found
$ echo $?
1

$ bash --init-file <( echo "type blah; echo $?" )
bash: type: blah: not found
0
```

Why is the return value different in an init script than it is in an interactive shell?

**Edit** And different again in the init script for an interactive shell:

```
$ bash --init-file <( echo "type blah; echo $?" ) -i
bash: type: blah: not found
2
```

Bash version is 4.4.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$?` is being evaluated *before* it's passed as an argument to the outer `echo` command. As a result, you're running the equivalent of:

```
bash --init-file <( echo "type blah; echo 0" ) -i
```

You can sort of see this using `set -x` mode which'll show the equivalent of the executed commands:

```
$ bash --init-file <( echo "type blah; echo $?" )
+ bash --init-file /dev/fd/63
++ echo 'type blah; echo 0'
bash: type: blah: not found
0
```

Note the third line, `++ echo 'type blah; echo 0'` -- the `$?` has already been expanded before it's passed to the `echo` command (and thence to the new shell to execute). BTW, this means that it's actually showing the result of the last command run *before* this one:

```
$ curl http://notarealdomain.example.com/
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: notarealdomain.example.com
$ bash --init-file <( echo "type blah; echo $?" )
bash: type: blah: not found
6
```

Note that the status printed, "6", is `curl`'s code for an unresolvable host error.

Anyway, the solution is simple: use single-quotes to delay evaluation of the `$?`:

```
$ bash --init-file <( echo 'type blah; echo $?' )
bash: type: blah: not found
1
```

Comment: Oh, FFS, sorry for a stupid question!

Answer (score 1):

### Answer first

1. The init-script does nothing to do with the return value.
2. The process substitution `<(...)` is the real cause.

### Explanation

**[Proof1]** Now try this command below. It has no option `--init-file`, but same output (with some trivial prints).

```
(exit 10)
bash <( echo "type blah; echo $?" )
```

**[Proof2]** Try following commands, and change the number in first one, you will find more different return value.

```
(exit 117)
bash --init-file <( echo "type blah; echo $?" )
```

**[Proof3]** What output do you see?

```
(exit 23)
cat <( echo "type blah; echo $?" )
```

I think you can understand Answer1 via the 3 proofs above. What about Answer2?

If you just type the simple command `echo "type blah; echo $?"` to run it, what result do you expect? You expect it will print `type blah; echo <num>`, of which the `<num>` is the return value of the last command. Right? We all know the `$?` will be replaced with a number, because we all know bash will perform parameter expansion on `$?`.

It is same in process substitution `<(...)`.

In Bash, commands which appear in a process substitution `<(...)` will be invoked in a subshell. Subshell is also a shell(Bash). So for the command `echo "type blah; echo $?"`, you will get the exactly same result in subshell as you run it straightforward in current shell, which means subshell will also perform parameter expansion on `$?`, just like what a bash does.

So when you are running `bash --init-file <(echo "type blah; echo $?")`, the content of the init-script file is actually `type blah; echo <num>` rather than `type blah; echo $?`.

### Deeper

Although in process substitution `<(echo "type blah; echo $?")` the `$?` is expanded by subshell, its value is affected by current shell. The value of `?` in subshell is as same as the one in current shell.

See the Proof2, the first command is `(exit 117)`, which makes the value of `$?` in current shell be 117. But it is expanded to 117 in subshell too.

This is because the commands appearing in process substitution `<(...)` are  invoked in a subshell environment that is a **duplicate** of the current shell environment.

So this explains in your question you showed different return value if you put option `-i` in the command. That is not the difference brought by option `-i`. That is because before that command, you definitely execute another command which returns 2.

### More words

In fact, there are three other forms working the same way as process substitution in bash.

1. Command substitution `$(...)` or `` `...` ``
2. Commands grouped with parentheses `(...)`
3. Builtin commands in pipeline  `<builtin cmd> | ...` or `... | <builtin cmd>` or `<builtin cmd> | <builtin cmd>`